# Add multiple inputs into an array react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

i am new to coding and i am looking at building a project to learn react, i am trying to do the following and i am kinda stuck

[image]

i want to add all these values into an array that would like like this

```
{
  option: {
    size: ["Small", "Medium", "Large"],
    color: ["Red", "Orange", "Blue"]
   }
}
```

How can i do this on react?

Comment: Are you just wanting to string split the "Variants" value to be assigned to the "Option" value used as a key? Or something else? What have you tried already? Do you have a [mcve] you could show us? SO isn't a code writing service and we can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see.

Comment: Please post your react code as well, and explain which part you are stuck on.

Comment: to be honest i am not sure how i can do it on react, i am still learning

Comment: That's ok. Can you share a code example for what you have currently and describe what isn't working as expected and what the desired behavior should be?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this ?
There are better ways of doing it of course, but the general idea is there.

```js
function App() {
  
  const data = {
    option:
        {
        size: ["Small", "Medium", "Large"],
        color: ["Red", "Orange", "Blue"]
     }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
          <p>Option</p>
          <input placeholder="Option"></input>
          <p>Variants</p>
          <input placeholder={data.option.size.join(', ')}></input>
          <p>Option</p>
          <input placeholder="Option"></input>
          <p>Variants</p>
          <input placeholder={data.option.color.join(', ')}></input>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```